# SolveAlways rejects inequality

Tags: equation-solving

I have two functions of `x`, `f` and `g`.  `f[x] = g[x] + 2`, but the exact form of `g[x]` is unknown. It is known that `g[x]` is well-formed, positive, continuous, differentiable, etc., but an exact representation is unknown.

What I would like to find are the conditions under which `f[x]` is positive. This is clearly whenever `g[x] > -2`, however, when I use `SolveAlways`:

```
f[x_] = g[x] + 2
SolveAlways[f[x] >= 0, x]
```

I get:

> SolveAlways::eqf: 2 + g[x] < 0 is not a well-formed equation. >>

Comment: `Reduce[g[x] + 2 >= 0]`

Comment: SolveAlways is not used when inequalities are involved - see the documentation. Reduce[f[x] == g[x] + 2 && f[x] > 0, Reals] will give you what you want.

Comment: @rasher Could you provide an answer instead of a comment so I can mark this question as answered? Thanks!  For whatever it is worth, I had read the help documentation but I thought that since != were used in the examples then inequalities would be alright as well.

Comment: Surely! One moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolveAlways is not used when inequalities are involved - see the documentation.

```
Reduce[f[x] == g[x] + 2 && f[x] > 0, Reals]
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: if you could take a look at a less trivial follow up question, I would be **very** grateful. [Reduce Cannot Solve Complicated Function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39783/reduce-cannot-solve-complicated-function)